# Paragraphs in a div, em does not work

Tags: html, css

```css
#div {
  width: 200px;
}
#p1 {
  width: 0.5em;
}
#p2 {
  width: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div">
    <p id="p1">p1</p>
    <p id="p2">p2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to set p1 to 50% of div and p2 to 20% of div using em but it does not seem to change anything. How should I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Set a background colour on the paragraphs. You'll see the width is working.

Comment: ya.. width is correct .

Comment: `em` is a typographic measure and only applied to `font-size`, `line-height` etc. For a box element use pixels, percentages or for example `vw` or `vh`.

Comment: @mch — No. In CSS terms it is a unit like any other. It is defined relative to the font size, but can be used *anywhere* that you can use a `<length>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the paragraphs to percentages of the parent, you should use percentages in your css. Em's are a length unit relative to font size, not to it's parent width, or height. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

If you also want the paragraphs to appear next to eachother, add "display: inline-block;"

```css
#div {
  width: 200px;
  background: silver;
}
#p1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
#p2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div">
    <p id="p1">p1</p>
    <p id="p2">p2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

em unit is relative to the font-size of the element. So the width you set 0.5em will be half of the font-size of the parent. If not set, it will take 16px as default. 
If DIV font-size is set to 20px, its children P sets width: 0.5em means 10px width. 
Same is happening in your example, P1 is set with 8px width since its taking 16px default font-size of the container.

So try using % unit if you want children to size themselves according to parent container.

Answer (score 0):

**Conversions based on 16px browser default size**

You need to give `div to 1em` so that your child elements can have width accordingly. Try changing 50% to 0.5em as below, it will give same result

```
#div {
  width: 1em;
}
#p1 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color : red
}
#p2 {
  width: 0.2em;
}
```

**OR**

```
#div {
      width: 1em;
    }
    #p1 {
      width: 0.5em;
      background-color : red
    }
    #p2 {
      width: 0.2em;
    }
```

For more please also check [PXtoEM](http://pxtoem.com/)

Hope it will help !!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#div {
  vm: 1%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:block;
}
#p1 {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-left:10px;
}
#p2 {
  width: 20%;
  display:inline-block;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div">
    <p id="p1">p1</p>
    <p id="p2">p2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `display:inline-block;`

```css
#div {
  width: 200px;
}
#p1 {
  width: 0.5em;
  display:inline-block;
}
#p2 {
  width: 0.2em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div">
    <p id="p1">p1</p>
    <p id="p2">p2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try putting 0.5 to 50%, you will find the difference, it is now working as needed

Answer (score -1):

P is not a container, must havn't width stylements (use divs for this job, as divs are containers) so it must work as this:

```css
#div {
  width: 200px;
}
#p1 {
  width: 1.5em;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
#p2 {
  width: 1em;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div">
    <div id="p1">
      <p>p1 - lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div id="p2">
      <p>p2 - lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that if you set container width under p size, it will overflow (as it's elemental, dear Whatson).